# PHP (json_encode, implode) store data in a txt file

Tags: php

I'm trying to store data in a .txt file..
The data is already appear on my HTML page but I couldn't know how to post them in a txt file or store them in a session.

In main page:

```
<?php
echo implode('<br/>', $res->email);
echo json_encode($res->password);
?>'
```

I want to do something like below:

```
<?php
    $login = "
    EMAIL   : $_POST['$res->email'];
    PASSWORD: $_POST['$res->password']; ";

    $path = "login.txt";
    $fp = fopen($path, "a");
    fwrite($fp,$login);
    fclose($fp);
    ?>
```

So this $_POST['$res->email']; doesn't work with me  I get in the login.txt:

```
EMAIL   : json_encode(Array)
PASSWORD: implode('<br/>', Array)
```

Comment: Some one tell me why they adding Dislike :)

Comment: Neither function calls nor `$_POST['$res->email']` work in string context. It's entirely unclear/unexplained what's the intention of using `$_POST` there. That would be a syntax error, and doesn't produce the showcased result. This question is probably answerable; but seems less useful to future users.

Comment: "This question is probably answerable; but not seems less useful to future users" @mario   I am also a user..  May I hire you to resolve this issue?

Comment: If you get to gold people will vote up disregarding what you write. In this community you will learn that if they cant help you they will vote you down. They dont try to help or encourage to do better questions, they punish you for asking. I usually leave the question a few days and then remove it to regain points.

Answer (score 1):

> Neither function calls nor $_POST['$res->email'] would work in [string/interpolation context](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

While unversed, you should assemble your text data line by line:

```
$login =  "    EMAIL   : ";                  # string literal
$login .= implode('<br/>', $res->email);     # append function/expression result
$login .= CRLF;                              # linebreak
$login .= "    PASSWORD: ";                  # string literal
$login .= json_encode($res->password);       # append function/expression result
$login .= CRLF;                              # linebreak
```

And instead of the oldschool fopen/fwrite, just use [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) with `FILE_APPEND` flag.

Answer (score 1):

When you use post data you recieve it in your php file. You dont send post data from a php file. With that in mind you manipulate this data with php in the following way:

If is data you recieved from post:

```
echo $_POST['field'];
```

This will show the message stored on the field variable among the posted data. But check that the field will be always a string (even though the contents may not be so)
If you want  to acces dynamically a field just have in mind that it should be a string for example:

```
$email = "example@gmail.com";
echo $_POST[$email]
```

This will NOT return the posted email, but will return the contents from a variable inside Post called "example@gmail.com". Which is the same as :

```
echo $_POST["example@gmail.com"];
```

But making now a correct example. if you have this html in your webpage

```
<form action="/yourphp.php" method="post" target="_blank">
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

you will be able to recover the data from the input field named "email"

```
echo $_POST['email'];
```

and this will return the email inside the input.

After you have this clear, you can manipulate the data in different ways to send them to a file, but usually you will have to instantiate a handler, open a file, write content, save and close the file, all depending on your handler.